# Implementing class: Cannot find superclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, superclass

I have *ForceGaugeViewController* class and *ForceGaugeController* class. I'm trying to make the ForceGaugeController class be a subclass of ForceGaugeViewController, but I'm receiving errors.

Error:

> Cannot find interface declaration for ForceGaugeViewController
>   superclass of ForceGaugeController class.

ForceGaugeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <math.h>
#import "HardwareController.h"
#import "ForceGaugeController.h"

@interface ForceGaugeViewController : UIViewController{
}
end
```

ForceGaugeViewController.m

```
#import "ForceGaugeViewController.h"

@implementation ForceGaugeViewController
```

ForceGaugeController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ForceGaugeViewController.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"

@class ForceGaugeViewController;

// error here
@interface ForceGaugeController : ForceGaugeViewController{
}
@end
```

ForceGaugeController.m

```
#import "ForceGaugeController.h"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not only forward reference a class that you will inherit from or a protocol that you will implement. You just need to import the superclass in the header which you are already doing and then remove the `@class` declaration.

Edit: Also the superclass `ForceGaugeViewController` should not include the subclass `ForceGaugeViewController` in the header file.

**ForceGaugeController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ForceGaugeViewController.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"

@interface ForceGaugeController : ForceGaugeViewController{
 }
@end
```

Comment: Why would you `#import "ForceGaugeController.h"` into `ForceGaugeController.h`?

Comment: You can't ONLY forward declare a class that you will inherit from or a protocol that you will implement. It's not illegal (although bad style) to do both.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I didn't notice I had subclass in the superclass header file. It worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

**Be sure to avoid circular imports:**
Make sure you do not import any of the header or implementation subclasses files into the superclass file where the superclass interface declaration is (.h file)

Answer (score 1):

You're including ForceGaugeController.h in ForceGaugeViewController.h
 and including ForceGaugeViewController.h in ForceGaugeController.h. Circular includes will confuse the compiler and that's probably what's wrong.

A header file for a class only needs to include the framework (ie. UIKit), the subclass, and any protocols the class conforms to. Forward declarations will do for the classes of instance instance variables/method arguments/properties.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
@class ForceGaugeViewController;
```

You are already importing the *ForceGaugeViewController* class via its header file at the top of your ForceGaugeController.m file.

---

***EDIT 1***

And as pointed out by @Chris Devereux, you have a circular reference in your header files, you will want to get rid of that as well.

---

***EDIT 2***

And not sure how I missed the self-import in your ForceGaugeController.h file. I assume that it's a typo, but if not I'm sure you know you have to remove it.